# Insert into table on conflict do update from csv

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have a table with two columns, `id` that is varchar and `data` that is jsonb. I also have a csv-file with new IDs that I would like to insert into the table, the data I would like to assign to these IDs are identical, and if an ID already exists I would like to update the current data value with the new data. This is what I have done so far:

```
INSERT INTO "table" ("id", "data") 
VALUES ('[IDs from CSV file]', ' {dataObject}') 
ON CONFLICT (id) do UPDATE set data='{dataObject}';
```

I have got it working with a single ID, but I would now like to run this for every ID in my csv-file, hence the array in the example to illustrate this. Is there a way to do this using a query? I was thinking I could create a temporary table and import the IDs there, but I am still not sure how I would utilize that table with my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use a staging table to upload your csv into, make sure to truncate it before uploading. After uploading:

```
insert into prod_table
   select * from csv_upload
      on conflict (id) do update
         set data = excluded.data;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't complicate the process unnecessarily.

1. Import csv to a temporary table T2
2. Update T1 where rows match in T2
3. Insert into T1 from T2 where rows do not match